# WebDriver Position Loop

Tags: python, selenium

I multithread with Selenium, so I launch like 7-8 windows at once, I want them all to align one next to another, how do I go about doing this.

Ive tried this. B

```
x = 20
y = 25
while (x, y < 60):
    driver.set_window_position(x, y)
    x = x + 10
    x = x - 5
    y = y + 10
    y = y - 15
```

But it just goes off screen like a pacman game..

Comment: Your while condition is incorrect. Are you trying to compare (x + y) < 60 which will always equal to 45. Also, inside your while you can simplify using y -= 5 and x += 5

Comment: I was just testing to be honest, so what would it equal didn't matter to me.

Comment: It does matter, as it will always be true. x will go to +infinity and y will go to -infinity.

Comment: I understand, but it was just a test.

Comment: I'm just looking on how to align windows one next to other.

Comment: How many columnsand rows? Lets say you have 8 windows to open. Are you looking for 4x2 ?

Comment: Yeah, thats what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple to achieve the request. This will open a 4x2 and place each browser in their respective position:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

# pip3 install screeninfo - might work to get the info but did not work on my macOS
screen_height = 1080
screen_width = 1920

number_of_session = 8
number_per_row = 4
number_per_column = number_of_session / number_per_row

driver_height = screen_height / number_per_column
driver_width = screen_width / number_per_row


drivers = []

row = 0
column = 0
for idx in range(number_of_session):
    driver = Chrome()
    drivers.append(driver)
    driver.set_window_rect(column * driver_width, row * driver_height, width=driver_width, height=driver_height)
    if idx + 1 == number_per_row:
        row += 1
        column = 0
    else:
        column += 1

for driver in drivers:
    driver.close()
```

Comment: That opens infinite amount of those

Comment: It will only open the number_of_session (8).

Comment: Nope, it opened many more after 8. I'll check again in 10-20mins but it opened way more than 8.

Comment: Sure let me know, as this is odd. We are using for loop, so it should iterate only for the range set

Comment: oh that would explain it. Code is not implemented for thread. You can definitely move it to a method and then use threads. Passing row/column to the method. Can you try without thread and if it works and answers your question please don't forget to mark it as an accepted answer.

Comment: @Slownix- Did this answer work for you? If so can you accept the answer or provide more information so i can better help you? Thanks